# Filming a Bike From The Angle of The Wheel

Tags: video

I'm filming a chase scene for a course and want to incorporate a bike. I've seen multiple films where the angle is on the spokes of the wheel. I am looking for any suggestions of a (much cheaper) rig or idea to get this shot. I'm working with a Mark II. I have access to a monopod, a wheel rig, and a shoulder rig.

Thanks

Comment: A Mark II what? 5D?

Answer (score 2):

Buy an action camera (GoPro, SJcam, Sony, knock off brand) and use one of the many accessories you can get and or some fancy duct tape work. This way you would be able to get closer to the frame and also use the camera for some other more artistic shots due to the size.

Otherwise you could build a rig using clamps and rods to support your main camera but this could make the bike side heavy and not as easy to ride.

I think the professionals (hollywood films) would probably build a side frame for the bike so the bike is more stable

Answer (score 1):

None of the rigging you currently have is likely to help.  You can probably build a custom clamping solution pretty cheaply, but I'd be a bit worried about how jarring the experience could be for the camera itself given that it could be quite a bumpy ride and trying to work in shocks for the mount would increase both cost, complexity and impact on bike performance considerably.

As other's have said, an action camera with purpose built mount is probably the best bet for cost/risk, but there's not really much of a perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

- Go to local electrical store and try to find some cable/wires like this:

  [image]

  Ask seller for very hard and most thick cable. You will need 1-2 meters. Remove isolation and take it to the bike. Make some turns around the video camera. Make a few more turns near the fork of the bicycle. Use the remaining wire, since the shaking will provoke large loads.
- If you have actioncam with aquabox, go to ebay/aliexpress and find any GoPro mounts with queries like "gopro mount tube" or "gopro mount bike". But something like this for $2:
  [image]